# Mudar a cor usando querySelector e onmouseover

Tags: javascript

Boa noite amigos, eu criei um código que toda vez que um botão é pressionado ele cria uma div... O problema é que eu preciso criar um modo usando querySelector e onmouseover, para, sempre que o mouse passar por cima de alguma dessas div ele troque a cor para outra aleatória, como faço pois sempre que inicio o código as divs ainda não existem, como eu as referencio para saber qual delas o mouse passou por cima?

Como podem ver eu consegui fazer com um botão mudar cor, mas o intuito é não ter botão.

```js
let btnCriar = document.querySelector('#btnCriar');
let btnRemover = document.querySelector('#btnRemover');
let btnMudarCor = document.querySelector('#btnMudarCor');
let nomes = ['Diego', 'Gabriel', 'Lucas'];

btnCriar.onclick = function createSquare() {

    let squareElement = document.createElement('div')
    squareElement.setAttribute('class', 'box');
    squareElement.style.width = 100;
    squareElement.style.height = 100;
    squareElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    document.body.appendChild(squareElement);
}

function getRandomColor() {

    let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    let color = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }

    return color;
}

btnMudarCor.onclick = function mudaCor() {
        let inputElement = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    for(let i = 0; i< inputElement.length; i++){
        inputElement[i].style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    }

}
```

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button class='botao' id='btnCriar'>Criar Quadrado</button>
<button class='botao' id='btnMudarCor'>Mudar Cor</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar o evento `onmouseover` assim que criar a `div`:

```
squareElement.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
}
```

---

```js
let btnCriar = document.querySelector('#btnCriar');
let btnMudarCor = document.querySelector('#btnMudarCor');

btnCriar.onclick = function createSquare() {
    let squareElement = document.createElement('div');
  
    squareElement.setAttribute('class', 'box');
    squareElement.style.width = "30px";
    squareElement.style.height = "30px";
    squareElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    squareElement.onmouseover = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    }

    document.body.appendChild(squareElement);
}

function getRandomColor() {

    let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    let color = "#";

    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }

    return color;
}

btnMudarCor.onclick = function mudaCor() {
    let inputElement = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

    for(let i = 0; i< inputElement.length; i++){
        inputElement[i].style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button class='botao' id='btnCriar'>Criar Quadrado</button>
<button class='botao' id='btnMudarCor'>Mudar Cor</button>
```